# Testing subscription with repeat()

Tags: java, project-reactor

I want to test a function that uses the `repeat()` operator on a deferred mono and subscribes to the result. In the test, I use the `TestPublisher` to simulate new values from the mono.

In a very simplified form, it looks like this:

```java
package de.cronos.mad.messages.backend;

import java.util.function.Supplier;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.publisher.TestPublisher;

public class RepeatTest {

    private static class TestSubject {
        public void logMonoValues(Supplier<Mono<String>> monoSupplier) {
            Mono.defer(monoSupplier).repeat().subscribe(System.out::println);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void repeatTest() {
        TestPublisher<String> testPublisher = TestPublisher.create();

        TestSubject testSubject = new TestSubject();
        testSubject.logMonoValues(testPublisher::mono);

        testPublisher.emit("Hello");
        testPublisher.emit("World");
    }
}
```

The execution hangs after logging "Hello" to stdout. I think I understand why this happens: The `emit(…)` call happens from the main thread and "drives" the subscription from there.

What I do not know is how to modify this test so that it completes, i.e. does not hang?

Comment: Can you share the `TestPublisher` ? I replaced the TestPublisher with DirectProcessor. It just works fine.

Comment: @vins: Sure, it's from the official test package (https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/publisher/TestPublisher.html) and described in the documentation (https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_manually_emitting_with_testpublisher).

Comment: @vins: I tried to replaced the TestPublisher with DirectProcessor, like you suggested, but stdout is empty (although the test completes). I implemented it like this: https://gist.github.com/davidbilge/1cd1c812658160526a4cc14f21bf78c5 (note that TestPublisher's `emit()` means `next()` + `complete()`).

Comment: @vins: I accidentally used a parallel scheduler which led to the test completing without writing to stdout. After removing it, the code hangs like when using the TestPublisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes:

1. The `.repeat()` operator when used without arguments means to repeat indefinitely. It initiates a new subscription immediately once the original one completes successfully. Two ways to terminate it are:

   1. Limit the count of iterations, e.g. as `.repeat(10)`, as suggested by *vins*;
   2. Abort the sequence by sending an error signal, e.g. with `Mono.error(Throwable)` or just by throwing an exception.
2. Calling `testPublisher::mono` declares that this instance of `TestPublisher` adheres to a `Mono` contract, i.e. only sends a single value.

   Thus neither calling `.emit()` twice, nor calling it with two arguments will help. Extra values will be ignored.
3. The javadoc for [TestPublisher](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/publisher/TestPublisher.html) says,

   > TestPublisher are generally hot, [...] replaying the first termination signal to subsequent subscribers.

   It means that late subscribers immediately receive the termination signal. The subscriptions created by `repeat()` operator immediately receive the replayed termination signal, which in turn causes `repeat()` to resubscribe, in a tight loop.

I think that a possible solution is to use `Mono.defer()` or `Mono.fromSupplier()` to create a new value for each subscription created by `.repeat()`. E.g.:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class So63117029 {

  private static class TestSubject {
    public void logMonoValues(Supplier<Mono<String>> monoSupplier) {
      Mono.defer(monoSupplier).repeat().subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedBlockingQueue<String> data = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(List.of("Hello", "World"));

    TestSubject testSubject = new TestSubject();
    testSubject.logMonoValues(() -> Mono.fromSupplier(data::remove));
  }
}
```

The method `Queue.remove()` throws a `NoSuchElementException` when there is no more data in the queue.

Comment: This is almost there, although, as you say, there is a `NoSuchElementException` being thrown, which fails the test.

Comment: I extended my test a little using `takeUntilOther(…)` to stop the infinite `repeat()`. I put the working result in a gist: https://gist.github.com/davidbilge/08a77f21dae9dada764436727c0921db

Answer (score 0):

The TestPublisher `emit` method accepts array of values. Once emitted, it closes the source. So you can not emit one by one. Instead pass all the values like this.

```
testPublisher.emit("Hello", "world");

// from TestPublisher emit
public final TestPublisher<T> emit(T... values) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(values, "values array is null, please cast to T if null T required");
    Object[] var2 = values;
    int var3 = values.length;

    for(int var4 = 0; var4 < var3; ++var4) {
        T t = var2[var4];
        this.next(t);
    }

    return this.complete();
}
```

Regarding the hanging behavior,  the `repeat` here seems to cause the issue as it  indefinitely tries to reconnect the source Mono again and again.

```
Mono.defer(monoSupplier).repeat().subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Just change it like this to understand the behavior.

```
Mono.defer(monoSupplier).repeat(10).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: "Once emitted, it closes the source": That is exactly the point. If the source completes, this causes the `repeat` operator to resubscribe. In the real usecase, this would cause an http call to be issued. That is the behavior I want to simulate in my test.

Comment: @David, your understanding is right. But do note that you have 2 different sources. One is TestPublisher and other one is Mono. You do the repeat for the monosource which in turn depends on the Test Publisher. The repeat will resubscribe to mono. but it does not have anything to emit as it parent source is already complete.

Comment: Note that I use `Mono.defer`, which takes a Mono-supplier. On each resubscribe, the supplier is called and returns a new Mono. But you are right: The TestPublisher has completed, and calling `mono()` on it again does not change that. Still, simply `next`ing multiple values does not test the repeat mechanism of the test subject.